# Add Sub child Nodes in TreeView

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

How to Add Sub Child Nodes of Node's Child ?

```
{
    TreeNode treeNode = new TreeNode("Windows");
    treeView1.Nodes.Add(treeNode);

    treeNode = new TreeNode("Linux");
    treeView1.Nodes.Add(treeNode);

    TreeNode node2 = new TreeNode("C#");
    TreeNode node3 = new TreeNode("VB.NET");
    TreeNode[] array = new TreeNode[] { node2, node3};

    node2 = new TreeNode("Child Nodes", array);
    treeView1.Nodes.Add(node2);
}
```

Comment: Try `node2.nodes.add(whatever)`: this will add a subnode to `node2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This

```
       {
        TreeNode treeNode = new TreeNode("Windows");
        TreeNode node2 = new TreeNode("C#");
        TreeNode node3 = new TreeNode("VB.NET");
        node2.Nodes.Add("whatever");
        treeNode.Nodes.Add(node2);
        treeNode.Nodes.Add(node3);
        treeView1.Nodes.Add(treeNode);
        treeNode = new TreeNode("Linux");
        treeView1.Nodes.Add(treeNode);
       }
```

Comment: Way to go @user3291757!

Answer (score 0):

below code will help you

```
        TreeNode treeNode = new TreeNode("Windows");
        TreeNode node2 = new TreeNode("C#");
        TreeNode node2Sub = new TreeNode("C#-Sub");
        TreeNode node2SubToSub = new TreeNode("C#-Sub-Sub");
        node2Sub.Nodes.Add(node2SubToSub);  
        node2.Nodes.Add(node2Sub); 
        TreeNode node3 = new TreeNode("VB.NET");
        treeNode.Nodes.Add(node2);
        treeNode.Nodes.Add(node3);
        treeView1.Nodes.Add(treeNode);
        treeNode = new TreeNode("Linux");
        treeView1.Nodes.Add(treeNode);
```

Comment: "ChildNodes" Has no definition in C# for tree view , i am getting this error.

Comment: Oh sorry please take look again answer

Comment: This will just give me child nodes i want sub child nodes(child nodes of child node)

Comment: @user3291757 Gave my desired answer thank you for your effort :)